# Strange AJAX problem (SOMETIMES works in Chrome/FF, ALWAYS works in Midori)

Tags: ajax

I have an ajax function that sometimes doesn't work in Chrome and Firefox (doesn't load the data), but displays no errors in the console. However, it ALWAYS works in the Midori browser (Bhodi distro). Can anyone see anything sketchy in my code, or perhaps know how to go about debugging this?

**Functions.php :**

```
function my_dropdown_categories( $taxonomy, $current_selected = '', $include = null )  {
/*
 * Declare your variable first. Without this, your code has a bug if no terms are found
 */
$list_of_terms = '';

$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'parent' => 0 ) );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {

    $list_of_terms .= '<select id="location" class="selectboxSingle" name="location">';

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        // If include array set, exclude unless in array.
        if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $term->slug, $include ) ) continue;

        $select = ($current_selected == $term->slug) ? "selected" : ""; // Note: ==

        /*
         * Use the parent term term id as parent to get direct children of the term
         * Use child_of if you need to get all descendants of a term
         */
        $uchildren = get_terms( $taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' => $term->term_id ));

        $children = array();
        foreach ($uchildren as $child) {
            // If include array set, exclude unless in array.
            if ( is_array( $include ) && ! in_array( $child->slug, $include ) ) continue;
            $children[$child->name] = $child;
        }
        ksort($children);

        // PARENT TERM      
        if ($term->count > 0) {
            $list_of_terms .= '<option class ="group-result" value="'.$term->slug.'" '.$select.'>' . $term->name .' </option>';
        } else {
            $list_of_terms .= '<option value="'.$term->slug.'" '.$select.'>'. $term->name .' </option>';
        };

        // now the CHILDREN.
        foreach($children as $child) {
            $select = ($current_selected == $child->slug) ? "selected" : ""; // Note: child, not cterm
            $list_of_terms .= '<option class="result-sub" value="'.$child->slug.'" '.$select.'>'. $child->name.' </option>';
        } //end foreach

    }

    $list_of_terms .= '</select>';

}
return $list_of_terms;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt', 'wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt', 'wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt' );

function wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt() {
$ret = array( 'html' => '', 'error' => false );

if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt_submit_', 'nonce', false /*die*/ ) ) {
$ret['error'] = __( 'Permission error', 'wpfm' );
} else {
$post_type = isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) ? $_REQUEST['post_type'] : '';
$taxonomy = isset( $_REQUEST['taxonomy'] ) ? $_REQUEST['taxonomy'] : '';
$current_selected = isset( $_REQUEST['current_selected'] ) ? $_REQUEST['current_selected'] : '';

if ( ! $post_type || ! $taxonomy ) {
    $ret['error'] = __( 'Params error', 'wpfm' );
} else {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT t.slug FROM ' . $wpdb->terms . ' t'
        . ' JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . ' AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id'
        . ' JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . ' AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id'
        . ' JOIN ' . $wpdb->posts . ' AS p ON p.ID = tr.object_id'
        . ' WHERE tt.taxonomy = %s AND p.post_type = %s AND p.post_status = %s'
        . ' GROUP BY t.slug'
        , $taxonomy, $post_type, 'publish' );
    $include = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
    $ret['html'] = preg_replace( '/<\/?select[^>]*>/', '', my_dropdown_categories( $taxonomy, $current_selected, $include ) );
}
}

wp_send_json( $ret );
}
```

**Frontpage :**

```
        <div class="show-on-load">
        <div class="search">
            <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
                <?php
                //$post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type($post) ); // GET SINGULAR NAME
                $args = array(
                'public'   => true,
                '_builtin' => false
                );
                $output = 'objects'; // names or objects, note names is the default
                $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
                $post_types = get_post_types($args, $output, $operator);
                ksort($post_types);
                echo '<select class="hide-placeholder fade-in three selectboxSingle" name="post_type">';
                echo '<option value="" disabled selected>I\'m looking for:</option>';
                foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
                $exclude = array('custom_type');
                if(TRUE === in_array($post_type->name,$exclude)){
                continue;
                }

                echo '<option value="'.$post_type->query_var.'">' . ucfirst($post_type->labels->singular_name) . '</option>';
                }
                echo "</select>";
                ?>

                <?php 
                // Set your custom taxonomy
                $taxonomy = "location";
                // Factored out taxonomy dropdown into function my_dropdown_categories() in "functions.php".
                echo my_dropdown_categories( $taxonomy );
                ?>

                <div class="submit-button-blanket">
                    <button class="submit-button alt" type="submit">Search</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var flag, flag2;
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('select[name="post_type"]').change(function (event) {
    //flag = new Date().getTime();
    $('select[name="location"]').html("<option value=''>Searching...</option>");
    if ($('select[name="post_type"]').val() === 'test1') {
        $('#location').prop('disabled', true);
        $('select[name="location"]').html("<option>TEST1</option>");
        $('.submit-button').fadeTo(500,1);
    };

    $(".selectboxSingle").trigger("chosen:updated");            
        $.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", {
            action: 'wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt',
            post_type: $(this).val(),
            taxonomy: <?php echo json_encode( $taxonomy ); ?>,
            current_selected: $('select[name="location"]').val(),
            nonce: <?php echo json_encode( wp_create_nonce( 'wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt_submit_' ) ); ?>
        }, function( response ) {
            if ( response && !response.error ) {
                $('select[name="location"]').html(response.html);
        if ($('select[name="post_type"]').val() === 'test2') {
            return false;
        }else{
                $('#location').prop('disabled', false);
                $(".selectboxSingle").trigger("chosen:updated");
                $('.submit-button').fadeTo(500,1);
            }}
        }, 'json'
    ); 
});


// Remove if you don't want to call change immediately.
$('#location').prop('disabled', true);
//  $('.submit-button').prop('disabled', true);
$('select[name="post_type"]').change();
$('select[name="location"]').html("<option>---</option>");
 /*
//$('.submit-button').prop('disabled', true);
$('.submit-button').hide(1);
$("#location").prop("disabled", true);*/

});
```

Comment: This code (some of which is beautifully crafted :) works for me as it in Firefox and Chrome - is it that you're trying to use it with Chosen?

Comment: Hi @bonger, sorry for the late response! Yes, I'm trying to use it with Chosen. It works most of the time, then sometimes it just doesn't, with no errors. It's very confusing...?

Comment: So it works without using Chosen? I confess I don't like Chosen, which I found buggy and abandoned using and much prefer select2 https://select2.github.io/ which you might try instead...

Comment: I've tried select2 and selectize, but for some reason they didn't quite fit the bill. Maybe I need to play around with them a bit more. Thanks so much though :)